# Either you are wrong, or I. Can I change it to 'Either you or I am wrong.'?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Either you are wrong, or I

Can I change it to **Either you or I am wrong.**?

Or can I change it to **Either you *are* or I am wrong.**

In **Either you or I am wrong.**, it contains the meaning: You are wrong or I am wrong. But there is not **are** in **Either you or I am wrong.**.

Comment: What do you think? Please explain what you have done to try to work this out, why you think you can do it, or why you think you can't.

Comment: @SamBC I think **Either you or I am wrong.** is wrong. For I think it means: **Either you  am or I am wrong.**. I think just **Either you are or I am wrong.** is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your sentences is grammatical.

The full version of the sentence, which is grammatical, is:

> Either you **are** wrong or I **am** wrong.

The only way of shortening it by just removing a word (while maintaining the grammar) is:

> Either you **are** wrong or I **am**.

---

You could also rephrase it differently (assuming it's the singular *they*) by simply saying:

> One of us is wrong.

---

Note that the two shorter versions in the question are ungrammatical because the parallel structures would expand into incorrect subject-verb agreement:

> ✘ Either you are wrong or I [are wrong].
>   ✘ Either you [am wrong] or I am wrong.

In order to prevent this, the two different verb forms have to be made explicit.

Comment: So, are my two sentences wrong?

Comment: @Y.zeng Yes, I've modified my answer to make that clear.

Comment: God, I guessed two sentences will be all right, but I can not confirm. Now, you tell me both of them are wrong. But can you tell me why they are wrong?

Comment: @Y.zeng I've moved my comment into the answer itself.

Comment: But I once saw this sentence: 'Either one rat or several mice are eating everything in the cupboard'. This sentence contary to you answer.

Comment: @Y.zeng That sentence is understandable—but it should really be rephrased. It only *sounds* correct because you're reading *several mice are eating*. But, in reality, it's no better than saying *either several mice or one rat is eating*. Whichever order you put it in, the verb will disagree with one of the subjects. On the other hand *one rat* ***and*** *several mice are eating* is fine, because *either* has not been used and it's a plural combined subject.

Comment: Okay, I will remember this.

Comment: **one rat and several mice**? Are **rats** = **mice**?

Comment: Either you are or I am wrong.  How about this?

Comment: I found this (https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/either_or_plural_or_singular_verb.htm）, which may be comprehensive.